# Vaadin - deleting temporary Files from Upload-Component

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

hope you can help me. I have a Spring-Boot vaadin-Project with a few Upload-Fields.
Everythings fine. if you click on the send button in the end everything is processed and tempfiles are deleted. Though when you upload a file and leave the site then the temp-directory stays untouched. Is there  any way to programatically delete all temporary files when a new instance is called?

When I upload a file on a built-with-vaadin-website and leave the site then, my temp directory gets fuller and fuller. i just want to delete all files which were created in the actual Vaadin Session when starting a new one. Or is there a way to find all files created in a spring session periodically?

Comment: A possible solution is to run a cron job (e.g. once an hour) and delete everything in the `tmp`-directory that is older than - for example - 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom VaadinServiceInitListener class (annotated with @Component), I would make a deleting method and in the serviceInit method I would call the deleting method with the uploading path. Something like this:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationServiceInitListener
    implements VaadinServiceInitListener {

  @Override
  public void serviceInit(ServiceInitEvent event) {
      // Delete the upload directory's content
      try {
          deleteDirectory(new File("[your_upload_directory_path]"));
      } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      // ...
  }

  private boolean deleteDirectory(File directoryToBeDeleted) {
      File[] allContents = directoryToBeDeleted.listFiles();
      if (allContents != null) {
          for (File file : allContents) {
              deleteDirectory(file);
          }
      }
      return directoryToBeDeleted.delete();
  }
```

}

Service Init Listener Vaadin doc: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/service-init-listener

Ps: Of course, you can also use a File Util class, e.g. from common-io.

Comment: The example above deletes all the files, not only the files are made in the current session. So what i thought I would mark the uploaded files name with the session id somehow. But the files easly left there if the server shut down and doesn't rerun again - nor new session created.